# How can you deploy a Python project created in Visual Studio to Heroku?

Tags: python, visual-studio, heroku

When creating a Python project, Visual Studio creates following structure:
Your repository/solution folder: it contains Readme.md, .sln file and project folder.
Within that project folder are all your scripts (.py files with code) and a .pyproj file.

To deploy the project to Heroku I copied all of the files inside the project folder to a separate folder, manually created requirements.txt, manually created Procfile (which referenced my main .py script), created an empty __init__.py file; then pushed it all to GitHub.

The code (a Telegram bot) works as needed when I build it in Visual Studio (by pressing F5), but the behaviour is slightly different when it's deployed on Heroku: it only correctly reacts to the first message sent to it, and ignores the next ones. It seems like it only runs once when it's deployed as opposed to running on loop.

What have I missed? Should've I included the .pyproj and .sln files somehow when deploying to Heroku?

P.S. My project structure is simple. I have two .py scripts: one with the main logic and the other with tests. Inside the main .py file there's this block:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```